# iOS / Objective-C : UICollectionView protocol definitions and iOS 5

Tags: objective-c, ios5, ios6, uicollectionview

I've yet to make a Auto-Layoutless Storyboard to running on iOS 5 so my code won't even run on iOS 5 at the moment. However, I do plan on supporting it. At the same time, I also want to incorporate collection views in my app. I will support it on iOS 5 through the use of the publicly available [PSTCollectionView on github](https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView). I figure, define the collection view `IBOutlet` as an `id` and then everything else is simple. Expect one thing...

Defining the delegate and datasource the collection views is a must.

So my question is, upon defining the `UICollectionViewDelegate` and `UICollectionViewDataSource` in my view controller

a. will my project even compile for iOS5 devices?

b. if not, how do I add a macro to conditionally define the respect protocols on iOS5 and iOS6?